# Unknown arg `id` in data.employee.id for type EmployeeCreateNestedOneWithoutComputerInput

Tags: node.js, prisma

I'm having those issues when trying to create data (using `prisma.create({})`):

```
Unknown arg `id` in data.employee.id for type EmployeeCreateNestedOneWithoutComputerInput. Available args:

type EmployeeCreateNestedOneWithoutComputerInput {
  create?: EmployeeCreateWithoutComputerInput | EmployeeUncheckedCreateWithoutComputerInput
  connectOrCreate?: EmployeeCreateOrConnectWithoutComputerInput
  connect?: EmployeeWhereUniqueInput
}
Unknown arg `name` in data.employee.name for type EmployeeCreateNestedOneWithoutComputerInput. Did you mean `create`? Available args:
type EmployeeCreateNestedOneWithoutComputerInput {
  create?: EmployeeCreateWithoutComputerInput | EmployeeUncheckedCreateWithoutComputerInput
  connectOrCreate?: EmployeeCreateOrConnectWithoutComputerInput
  connect?: EmployeeWhereUniqueInput
}
Unknown arg `phone` in data.employee.phone for type EmployeeCreateNestedOneWithoutComputerInput. Did you mean `create`? Available args:
type EmployeeCreateNestedOneWithoutComputerInput {
  create?: EmployeeCreateWithoutComputerInput | EmployeeUncheckedCreateWithoutComputerInput
  connectOrCreate?: EmployeeCreateOrConnectWithoutComputerInput
  connect?: EmployeeWhereUniqueInput
}
Unknown arg `email` in data.employee.email for type EmployeeCreateNestedOneWithoutComputerInput. Did you mean `create`? Available args:
type EmployeeCreateNestedOneWithoutComputerInput {
  create?: EmployeeCreateWithoutComputerInput | EmployeeUncheckedCreateWithoutComputerInput
  connectOrCreate?: EmployeeCreateOrConnectWithoutComputerInput
  connect?: EmployeeWhereUniqueInput
}
```

Here's my Employee model:

```
model Employee {
  id       Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String     
  email    String     
  phone    String     
  status   Boolean    @default(true)
  computer Computer[]
}
```

The `Computer` model have this relation:

`employee       Employee      @relation(fields: [employee_id], references: [id])`

Prisma create function (service):

```js
static async createComputer(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
    try {
      const computer = await prisma.computer.create({
        data,
      });
      return computer;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(`Error: ${e}`);
    }
  }
```

Controller:

```js
export const createComputer = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const result = ComputerService.createComputer(req.body);
  result.then((computer: any) => {
    res.status(200).json({
      data: computer,
    });
  });
};
```

Angular frontend create request:

```js
createComputer(): void {
    let data: any = {
      description: this.description.value,
      erp: false,
      office_key: {
        id: this.office_key.value.id,
      },
      office_version: {
        id: this.office_version.value.id,
      },
      processor: {
        id: this.processor.value.id,
      },
      memory: {
        id: this.memory.value.id,
      },
      disk: {
        id: this.disk.value.id,
      },
      license: {
        id: this.license.value.id,
      },
      brand: {
        id: this.brand.value.id,
      },
      manufacturer: {
        id: this.manufacturer.value.id,
      },
      employee: {
        id: this.employee.value.id,
      },
      os: {
        id: this.os.value.id,
      },
      sector_id: 1,
      type: {
        id: this.type.value.id,
      },
    };
    try {
      this.computerService.create(data).subscribe(() => {
        console.log("Registro criado");
        this.dialogRef.close({ created: "ok" });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Erro: ${e}`);
    }
  }
```

Frontend service:

```
[...]

baseUrl = "http://localhost:8000/computers";

create(computer: Computer): Observable<Computer> {
    return this.http.post<Computer>(this.baseUrl, computer).pipe(
      map((obj) => obj),
      catchError((e) => this.errorHandler(e))
    );
  }
```

I'm doing a POST request with the entire object, also I tried only using the `id` of the relation to create the record and had the same error message.

Comment: Can you share the prisma create query that you are invoking?

Comment: Sure, added more information :)

Comment: You are trying to create a computer record but from the error message it seems that error is generated while creating an employee

Comment: the model "Computer" have a relation with the model "Employee"

but there's also more relations, with licenses, manufacturers, etc.

Comment: From the employee model it seems that id, name, email, status all are required but you are just passing the id while creating it?